# Export data into PDF file with dynamically generated nested table in Angular and jsPDF or PdfMake

Tags: angular

In the response of my API call, I get a Object with some child objects. Now I need to export these objects into a PDF file. The data will be showin in tabular format and there will be nested tables. The whole process is needed to be done in the Angular. I found there are library jsPDF and PdfMake, but I don't know how to generate the nested tabular data dynamically.

Here is my object structure:

```
export interface FieldDataDto {    
    fieldValue: string;
    createBy: string;
    creationTime: Date;
    creatorCountryName: string;
}

export interface FieldInfoDto {    
    fieldName: string;    
    fieldDataLists: FieldDataDto[];
}

export interface SectionInfoDto {
    sectionName: string;
    description: string;
    sectionFields: FieldInfoDto[];
}

export interface BundleDto {
    bundleName: string;
    description: string;
    surveySections: SectionInfoDto[];
}
```

Here is the JSON response of API call:

```
{
    "bundleName": "Survey Bundle Title",
    "description": "Survey Bundle Description",
    "surveySections": [
      {
        "sectionName": "Section-A Title",
        "description": "Section-A Description",
        "sectionFields": [
         {            
            "fieldName": "Field 1 Title",            
            "fieldDataLists": [
              {                
                "fieldValue": "Field 1 value",                
                "createBy": "User 1",
                "creationTime": "2023-07-26T13:53:28.6232875Z",
                "creatorCountryName": "Indonesia"
              }
            ]
          }, 
          {            
            "fieldName": "Field 2 Title",            
            "fieldDataLists": [
             {                
                "fieldValue": "Field 2 value",                
                "createBy": "User 2",
                "creationTime": "2023-07-26T13:53:28.6232875Z",
                "creatorCountryName": "India"
             }
            ]
          },
          {            
            "fieldName": "Field 3 Title",            
            "fieldDataLists": [
             {                
                "fieldValue": "Field 3 value",                
                "createBy": "User 2",
                "creationTime": "2023-07-26T13:53:28.6232875Z",
                "creatorCountryName": "India"
             }
            ]
          } 
        ]
      },
      {
        "sectionId": 30767,
        "sectionName": "Field Section Second",
        "description": "Field Section Second",
        "sectionFields": [
          {            
            "fieldName": "A. My Level",            
            "fieldDataLists": []
          },
          {            
            "fieldName": "Level 1",            
            "fieldDataLists": [
              {                
                "fieldValue": "By Norway",                
                "createBy": "NORWAY123 NORWAY123",
                "creationTime": "2023-07-26T11:11:11.3586988Z",
                "creatorCountryName": "Norway"
              }
            ]
          }                                                           
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Here is the possible Output:
[image]

**Is there anyone who can help me how to do this either jsPDF or PdfMake library. Or is therea any other better library for acheive my goal?**